# If an index is ensured on the opposite direction of a `sort()`, will it be used?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I was wondering if say, `sort(a:-1)` would use an index `ensured` on `a` but in the opposite direction (ie: `a:1`).

I am guessing this is true for a single key index, but I just wanted to be sure since I can't find the information in the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sorting by using single field indexes, order of keys doesn't matter because MongoDB can traverse the index in either direction. 
You can verify that by by using the explain command:

```
db.coll.find().sort({a: 1}).explain();
```

The relevant part of the output is (you should check the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#core-explain-output-fields) for the other fields in the output):

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_-1 reverse"
```

The `reverse` part means that MongoDB traversed the index in the reverse order.

However, if you're using compound indexes for sorting, the sort order matters. 
For example, take the following compound index:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({a: 1, b: -1});
```

This index can support these sorting operations:

```
db.coll.find().sort({a: 1, b: -1});
db.coll.find().sort({a: -1, b: 1});
```

But this index *can't* support this sorting operation:

```
db.coll.find().sort({a: 1, b: 1});
```

For more info about sorting, you should check the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order).